# Install powershell module programmatically

Tags: c#, powershell

My goal is to execute an exchange online powershell command in a docker image in a kubernetes server.
Manually, I would run the following commands in a powershell prompt:

- Install-module ExchangeOnlineManagement -force -AllowClobber
- Import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement
- then I would run my command such get-exomailbox

I do not manage to install the module programmatically (manually it works), I'm getting the following error:

{The term 'Install-module ExchangeOnlineManagement -force -AllowClobber' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.}  System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
this.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
this.Runspace.Open();
try
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.Runspace = Runspace;
    ps.Commands.AddCommand("Install-module ExchangeOnlineManagement -force -AllowClobber");
    ps.Invoke();
}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: `ps.Commands.AddCommand("Install-Module").AddArgument("ExchangeOnlineManagement").AddParameter("Force", true).AddParameter("AllowClobber", true);`

Comment: I'm still getting : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
It looks like a permissions issue as if the program was not allowed to run this command 
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted does not work and returns Operation is not supported on this platform.